# List of all the R keywords

Tags: r, emacs

I want to enable the auto-complete functionality in emacs for editing my R files. For this, I need to have listed all the keywords in the R language. Does someone know if this is available somewhere? I know I would have to include all the functions names in the external packages I am using, but for now the list of what is in r-cran-base should be fine for me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidRobinson it definitely helps, but it doesn't contain every keywords in R. For example, the followings are not there: return, apply, data.frame...

Comment: `data.frame` and `apply` aren't keywords. Neither are `plot`, `print` and many other functions/methods.

Comment: @HongOoi what do you mean by keyword? for me, it means all the expressions reserved by the language, such as return, apply, or data.frame. OF COURSE, I could (maybe, because I haven't tried) overwrite them, but I would never do that, and so I would need those for my auto complete to work.

Comment: But the language doesn't reserve the words you mention. Contrast what happens if you do `return <- 2` and `if <- 2`, for example.

Comment: Just use [Emacs/ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) where auto-complete is activated by default from 12.09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ls('package:base')
```

list all objects in a package

Comment: `ls(asNamespace("base"), all.names=TRUE)` is more complete.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just have to write the content of the output of that function into the file I will use to list my keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`apropos` with an empty string argument will list all objects on the search path. It is what is used for the tab complete in the default GUI.

```
apropos("")
   [1] "-"                                    
   [2] "-.Date"                               
   [3] "-.POSIXt"                             
   [4] "!"                                    
   [5] "!.hexmode"                            
   [6] "!.octmode"
   ...
```

Answer (score 4):

[The R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf) lists all of R's keywords. Note that those are also reserved.

> The following identifiers have a special meaning and cannot be used for object names
>
> if else repeat while function for in next break TRUE FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_
>   NA_complex_ NA_character_ ... ..1 ..2 etc.

Comment: Chapter 10.3.3 on page 48.

Answer (score 3):

See `?Reserved`, `?Control` and maybe `?Syntax` and `?Ops`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little heads up that what's being discussed here has nothing to do with actual R keywords, which is its own special thing. I suspect this is what @HongOoi is alluding to.
R keywords exists ostensibly to help group functions by theme, but, except for the special case of `internal`, isn't widely used.

If you want to see the list of valid keywords you can get it like this

```
readLines(file.path(R.home("doc"), "KEYWORDS.db"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might go to an R buffer and look at the following variable (given that you have [Emacs Speaks Statistics](http://ess.r-project.org/)):

```
ess-R-font-lock-keywords
```

by using `C-h v ess-R-font-lock-keywords`.

From there on, you can look in ess-custom.el and find everything you need on the implementation.

Comment: I don't think that @S4M uses ESS, as auto-complete is enabled there by default. Or I do not understand the question at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Just making sure you really want to do this since  `?rcompgen` describes the built-in functions by Deepayan Sarkar in the utils-package that already provide "tab-completion".